# How to inject spring aop advice for MongoDb call?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-aop

I am new to Spring Aop, but I have case to implement AOP advice for a mongo db call(monog db update). I am trying in different way but getting 'Point cut not well formed' error or 'warning no match for this type name: arg string [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]'(even if I give absolute name of the argument). Anyone can help on this as how to inject advice for mongo db update call?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DBStatsLoggerAspect {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(DBStatsLoggerAspect.class);

    private static final Document reqStatsCmdBson = new Document(
            "getLastRequestStatistics", 1);

    private DbCallback<Document> requestStatsDbCallback = new DbCallback<Document>() {

        @Override
        public Document doInDB(MongoDatabase db) throws MongoException,
                DataAccessException {
            return db.runCommand(reqStatsCmdBson);
        }
    };

    @After("execution( public * com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.*(..)) && args(org.bson.conversions.Bson.filter,..)")
    public void requestStatsLoggerAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = (MongoTemplate) joinPoint.getTarget();

        log.info(mongoTemplate.execute(requestStatsDbCallback).toJson());
    }

}
```

Actual db call method where I need to inject advice:(filter, updatePart all are org.bson.conversions.Bson data type) and here 'collection' is com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.collection

```
  Document result = collection.findOneAndUpdate(filter, updatePart, new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().upsert(false));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Spring or MongoDB user, just an AOP expert. But from what I see I am wondering:

- You are intercepting `execution(public * com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection.*(..))`, so `joinPoint.getTarget()` is a `MongoCollection` type. Why do you think you can cast it to `MongoTemplate`? That would only work if your `MongoCollection` happened to be a `MongoTemplate` subclass. To me this looks like a bug.
- Class `MongoCollection` is not a Spring component but a third-party class. Spring AOP can only intercept Spring component calls by means of creating dynamic proxies for those components and adding aspect interceptors to said proxies. so no matter how correct or incorrect your pointcut, it should never trigger.

What you can do instead is switch from Spring AOP to full-blown AspectJ. The standard way to do this is to activate [AspectJ load-time weaving (LTW)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).